# Display multiple guiqwt images (plots) in one window - Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, plot, qwt

I create plots using guiqwt and display them in 12 windows (each window displays one plot with few curves (1 to 4)). How can I show all plots in one window?

[image: ImageDialod Window Example]

Thanks!